# How to add a checkbox to a nodegroup

Tags: node-editor, groups

I am making a nodegroup and in it I have an option to invert the texture but it's a slider from 1-0 and you would only even need it to be either 1 or 0 so I was wondering if there was a way of adding a checkbox so it could be either one instead of something in between

Comment: I'm quite certain there isn't...I've wanted that for a while.

Comment: This guy here (creator of the Kaleidoscope Add-on) has managed to create nodes (not node groups) with a custom user interface: https://github.com/blenderskool/kaleidoscope . That would for you however mean to recreate the whole node group in code and provide it as an add-on.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is possible using regular Node Group creation alone, that is through the Blender user interface means. At least not without coding. Through Python scripting though, it might be possible, but not as trivial obviously